# Is it possible to get the typeTag of a runtime instance?

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime, scala-2.10

Using scala 2.10, I am trying to instantiate a class from a string and I would like to get its typetag.

for example :

```
scala> def printClassName[Y: TypeTag](x: Y) = { println(typeTag[Y].tpe) }
printClassName: [Y](x: Y)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Y])Unit
```

this is working :

```
scala> printClassName(new String())
String
```

But this is not :

```
scala> var foo = Class.forName("java.lang.String")
myInstance: Class[_] = class java.lang.String

scala> printClassName(foo)
java.lang.Class[?0]
```

Is there a way to overcome java erasure at runtime with scala ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can use the Scala Reflection api to get the `Type` (not `TypeTag`).  Not sure if this is what you wanted but it is the same thing being printed in `typeTag[Y].tpe`.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val classSymbol = m.staticClass("java.lang.String")
val tpe = classSymbol.selfType
```